# Searching from a range of ids in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I do something like this in range?

```
User.find(14000..14500)
```

I need to choose a certain range of Users starting and finishing on specifics ids.

Comment: mmm, have you read the AR guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-range_conditions

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) method:

```
User.where(id: 14000..14500)
```

#### Explanation

The `where` method here receives a hash argument in its shortened form, where the value for the `id` key is a [`Range`](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/range).

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this too:

```
User.find_by_id(14000..14500)
```

Comment: the OP wants a collection, so `find_all_by_id`.

Comment: find_by_id is handy because it doesn't break your application if it can't find a value at a given id

Answer (score 2):

You can use range definition for scoped:

```
User.find(1)       # returns the object for ID = 1
User.find([1])

User.find(1, 2, 9) # returns an array for objects with IDs in (1, 2, 9)
User.find([1, 2, 9])

User.scoped(:conditions => { :id => 1..9})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this also

```
User.find((start..end).to_a)
```

Ex -

```
User.find((14000..14500).to_a)
```