# Select items from database with id from x to y in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have very specific task. I need to select items from database with ids from certain range. (From 3 to 8 for example). How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching from a range of ids in ActiveRecord](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773160/searching-from-a-range-of-ids-in-activerecord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `where` with ranges:

```
Model.where(id: 3..8) # 3..8 - your range
```